# Download your Twitter followers' avatar pictures

Tags: twitter, profile-picture

I'm looking for a way to download all my followers' profile pics (48x48 px or bigger) in one run using either the Twitter API or some scripted scraping on twitter.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Get your list of friends](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/friends)
2. [Loop through each friend and get their profile pic](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show)

Comment: This obviously helped the Asker, but the goal of Stack Exchange is to build a repository of questions and answers that will help the many people who have the same question. That's not going to help if these links go away. Granted, they're from the Twitter dev site, and that will likely be around as long as Twitter, but sites have been known to re-organize and not redirect old links to new content.

Answer (score 1):

twilk does this: http://twilk.com/

So a week ago I found someone who gave the source code in a .Net application could not find it so quickly via Google but if you search for this combo you will find the source code.